# How can I link a single script for a multiple pages website?

Tags: javascript

I'm in a bit of a pickle.
I am making my portfolio, a multiple pages website made with `HTML`, `CSS` and `JS` (and `GSAP`).
I would like to have a single `CSS` and `JS` script for everything, to reduce the loading speed.
My problem is, I regularly get

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null

which makes sense because those errors refer to elements that are in other pages.
But it messes with the page I'm working on.

Is there a way I can make bits of code work only on specific pages, and not interfere with others?
I've tried applying an `ID` on each pages and specifying each `ID` when I use `querySelector`, `getElementById`... but it doesn't work.
I also saw something with `DOMContentLoaded`, but I'm not sure how it would work. Does anyone have any idea?

*I tried assigning ID, making sure there is no conflicting classes, making sure my script is at the bottom of my body*

Comment: it's doable, but it requires a methodical organization of your code. Like grouping all the declarations of your objects, at least by pages, but I imagine that some elements can end up on several pages? Otherwise test your elements to `undefined` before use

Comment: IMHO I think it's better to have a specific CSS and JavaScript file on each page, via a single-page application. So when you go to page hash: `#page1`, it will immediately retrieve (`page1.css`, `page1.js`), if you call `#page-test`, it will immediately retrieve (`page-test.css`, `page-test.js`), using the use of asynchronous calls. So this way you will always have only the bytes needed to render a specific page.

Comment: Another approach would be to load all the content of all your pages on a single page and use `<a href="#page-section1">` to allow the user to go to page "page-section1" or `<a href="#page-section2">` get to page "page-section2" and so on, adding smooth scrolling behavior, so you could easily get a better result using just a simple CSS file and a JavaScript file at a time. In this last approach, you'll need to use `<div id="page-section1"><h1>Page Section 1</h1><div>`, and so on, to each page that you have.

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez I did that at first, but I heard it hindered the loading speed of your website (since it needs to load many files). I think it may be fine for small projects, but starts becoming a problem when as it gets bigger...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any sophisticated method for this but I think this is one way you can do it.

But in this method, I guess you need to separate all the common JS codes required for all the pages and put them at the top of the script file without any condition.

```js
// In your single Javascript file check if the body has that particular page id
if(document.body.getAttribute('id') === 'page1'){
    /* When true it will execute only the scripts for page 1 (So you can copy-paste 
    all the codes for page 1 here and repeat this method for other pages)*/
    alert('page1');
}
```

```html
<!-- Set an id to each page like below: -->
<body id="page1">
    <h1>Page 1</h1>
</body>
```